# Draw 9-patch not working - cannot edit image

Tags: android

after I found out (sadly) that there is no easy way to create a simple border around a View, I was forced to use the 9-patch-image approach to get a border around my View.

So I read the short thing there is on the 9-patch and its easy enough to understand. I started the "Draw 9-patch" application that came with the Android SDK, opened up a very simple image I created in Paint and then... I got stuck.

According to the page (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) I should be able to define those areas where the image can be expanded and so on, just by clicking on the edges ("Click within the 1-pixel perimeter to draw the lines that define the stretchable patches...").

So I try to do just that and absolutely nothing happens. I try to hold down SHIFT when clicking and also do the rigth-mouse-click, and nothing happens. When I move the mouse away from the 1-pixel perimiter I get a grey-and-red "marquee" (stripes).

Bottom line is: nothing happens no matter what I do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The tool definitely works, but make sure the image you create first does NOT have the .9.png extension. If it does, the draw9patch tool will assume the 1 pixel perimeter of your image is already setup as 9-patch. If you open an image with just a .png extension, the tool will add the 1 pixel perimeter and you will be able to manipulate it as described, and save it as 9-patch when you're done.

Comment: Thx! the problem was that I named it .9.png at first =)
Now, the next problem is that I cannot add the "bottom" line since that "1 pixel perimiter" doesnt exist at the bottom, only to the left. Thus, I can add the line on the left, but not on the bottom or top - I cant see the perimiter there. any tips?

Comment: update: ok I can add the top, but the "perimiter" is hidden by the message "Press Shift to erase pixels"... Bottom is still a mystery, and to mark the right side is a hazzle since I need to scroll all the way to the right, so i cant see the image/shape anymore.

Comment: update 2: It is a scrolling problem it seems. If I fibble around with the right pane, I sometimes get the right "perimiter" that is usually missing. Bottom is still gone though.

Comment: update 3: ok, got it. Just made the image smaller, so no scrolling was required and then the perimiter showed up =)

Comment: @Ted, thanks, I was stuck with this for ages trying to find out why I couldn't draw the top edge, until I zoomed out :D

Comment: James: a late reply, but glad I could help =)

Answer (score 3):

The 9-patch tool is a bit awkward to use, but it does work. I believe you need to left click and drag around the edge to paint the outside border.

Alternatively, you can use any image editor and create a one pixel empty border around it, and draw in the following:

Top/Left = black pixels for the area of the image that can be grown or shrunk as needed.  For a typical border, it is everything except for the curved corners

Bottom/Right = black pixels for the small snippet that should be repeated if the image needs to be grown in that direction.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use just any image editor, you have to use the horrible draw9patch tool. I tried creating the black border in Photoshop but then I got this error when building: Compile Error: Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

**You must use a non-8bit png file to create a `.9.png` file, or it can not be edit.**
In my case, I can convert a 8-bit png to 9-patch file with Android Studio successfully, but I can't edit it anyway.
When I export the origin psd to normal png file, and convert it to 9-patch file, the 9-patch borders ban be edit now!